# Navigating from a Silverlight Child page

Tags: silverlight

I have an application that should redirect the logged-in user to a specific page.

My problem is that I am getting an error message off the child window::: MainPage mp = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual; How can I redirect in this case ?

```
/// <summary>
    /// Navigate to page that user is most likely to use.
    /// </summary>
    private static void NavigateToUserPage()
    {
        // Get logged in Role
        User user = WebContext.Current.User;

        // Count if collection > 1
        List<string> roles = new List<string>(user.Roles);

        if (roles.Count > 1)
        {
            // goto roles pages to select the user role
        }
        else
        {
            switch (roles[0])
            {
                case "SiteAdmin":
                    Uri uriSiteAdmin = new Uri("OwnerOccupier", UriKind.Relative);

                    MainPage mp = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual;
                    mp.ContentFrame.Navigate(uriSiteAdmin);
                    break;

                case "OwnerOccupier":
                    Uri uriOwner = new Uri("OwnerOccupier", UriKind.Relative);
                    MainPage p = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual;
                    p.ContentFrame.Navigate(uriOwner);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you want some help with an error you are getting it usually helpful if you include details about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Login window is called in LoginStatus user control under Views\Login in LoginButton_Click event handler. What you can actually do is in MainPage constructor where the content frame is located, you can subscribe to WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoggedIn event and in the event handler which will be called when the user is successfully authenticated, you can call ContentFrame.Navigate({enter uri here}).

Comment: Just to be clear I am trying to navigate from a login child form to silverlight window. So, If authentication is successfull.... navigate to window.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me what event fires to load the login window. There is no sign of any click event handlers and no clue in the XAML

Comment: I changed my answer. Take a look and see if this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Mehmet - am going to try and modify the Main Page constructor as you suggested

Comment: OK- that works ok - but I am still getting the error because the line of code :: MainPage mp = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual; .. is returning the BusyIndicator

Comment: Anyone know the solution to this please?

Comment: Why do you still need that line of code (Application.Current.RootVisual)? If you are handling the navigation in the main page as I suggested, you already have access to ContentFrame which provides a Navigate method for you to nativate to a page. Also exactly what error are you getting? what's the exception, stack trace,etc.?

Comment: I am handling the navigation in the MainPage as you suggested but i do not have access to a ContentFrame object. The ContentFrame has to be accessed through the MainPage object.... and that is where the problem is... and the error is ::: Unable to cast object of type 'MyComplex2.Controls.BusyIndicator' to type 'MyComplex2.MainPage'.

Comment: Sorry, this site wont take the code - attempted to upload the code but its failing to save... even thought its only 30 lines long

Comment: This is the code that is causing the error : MainPage mp = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual;

Comment: So ContentFrame (instance of Frame class) is not in main page? Then where is it? Find it and do the navigation in there where you have access to ContentFrame. Apparently and strangely RootVisual is of type MyComplex2.Controls.BusyIndicator and you are trying to cast it as MyComplex3.MainPage. Since two types are not compatible, you are getting an exception.

Comment: Correct. There is a navigation frame in the MainPage called ContentFrame. When logging in the busy indicator is showing and will continue to show until the LoggedIn event has completed....but this is where my business logic to redirect is being held. This is the cause of the problem. I have to find another place to put the code or find a way of navigating past the busy control - this whole thing seems unneccessarily complicated!!!

Comment: Here is another alternative: when the login dialog is closed, you will be back on the main page and the busy indicator will already be gone right? Currently, there is a login status control that launches the login dialog which is inaccesible from the main page. You can expose an event out of the login status control that lets the interested party know that the login dialog is closed. Since the login status is part of the main page, the main can subscribe to this event and when the event occurs, it navigates to the appopriate place depending on the authentication and authorization information.

Comment: I have put the code into UpdateLoginState() inside the LoginStatus control. I get exactly the same error message with the same cause. It seems all I am doing is moving the code from one class to another trying to avoid a BusyIndicator. Three days later and I am no closer to a solution to this extremely basic navigation task. How can this be so difficult.... bordering on impossible without expert help.... and this all to ONLY navigate to a user window. This stuff is unuseable!

Answer (score 1):

At some point in code you would have a called the `ChildWindow` `Show` method.  Before doing that add an event handler to the `Closed` event.  Put your navigation code in this handler rather than include it in your login `ChildWindow`.

Comment: I have not called anything - I am  using the standard business template - there is a login control on the Main form but now way of seeing how the events are fired - extremely frustrating

Comment: Its a loginstatus control ( whatever that is) - so where is the click event that get fired when the hyperlink gets clicked?